# How can I embed Ruby into Bootstrap Select Form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make this work? The drop down form shows up on the page, but the categories are just awkwardly floating below it and clicking on the form does nothing.

**_form.html.erb**

```html
<form>
    <select class="form-control">
    <%= f.collection_select :categories, Value::VALUES, :to_s, :to_s, :include_blank => true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Choose Category' %>
  </select>
</form>
```

**value.rb model**

```
class Value < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    VALUES = ['Courage', 'Determination', 'Gratitude', 'Humor']

end
```

**The whole form**

```html
<%= form_for(@value) do |f| %>
  <% if @value.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@value.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this value from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @value.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<div class="america">
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Value' %>
  </div>
  <select class="form-control">
    <%= f.collection_select :categories, Value::VALUES, :to_s, :to_s, :include_blank => true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Choose Category' %>
  </select>


  <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn") do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to values_path, class: 'btn' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to @value, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
  <% end %>
  </form>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [API docs for form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html).

```
<%= form_for @value do |f| %>
    <%= f.select :value, Value::VALUES %>
<% end %>
```

**Edit**

Modified for your example. I'm not sure if using a constant will work. You may need to pass those values to an instance or class variable in the controller.

Comment: How would this work for my situation tho? I tried replacing categories for person and a few other things but it didn't work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you give me more information about the form? What model is this data getting posted?